# Error: No such table exists SQLite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with two tables, one for holding Login information, such as Email adress and password, and the other one to hold GPS coordinates for the user. I create both tables in the OnCreate method in my DBadapter class "DatabaseHandler.class".
The login table works perfectly but the Coordinates table doesn't. The program throws "no such table exists" when I try to access and run commands on it.

*Logcat*

```
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidbasic12/com.example.androidbasic12.map}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: coord (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM coord WHERE name = name
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: coord (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM coord WHERE name = name
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.example.androidbasic12.library.DatabaseHandler.getLatLng(DatabaseHandler.java:155)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.example.androidbasic12.library.UserFunctions.getCoords(UserFunctions.java:124)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at com.example.androidbasic12.map.onCreate(map.java:56)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-22 12:42:06.769: E/AndroidRuntime(854):  ... 11 more
```

*DatabaseHandler.class*

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

//Carcoord table name
private static final String TABLE_CARCOORD = "coord";
// carcoord table columns names
private static final String CAR_KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String CAR_KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String CAR_KEY_LAT = "lat";
private static final String CAR_KEY_LNG = "lng";


// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";
// Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

//Strings that handles create table querys
private static final String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
        + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
        + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
private static final String CREATE_CARCOORD_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CARCOORD + "("
        + CAR_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + CAR_KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + CAR_KEY_LAT + " TEXT,"
        + CAR_KEY_LNG + " TEXT" + ")";

//Constructor
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CARCOORD_TABLE);

}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CARCOORD);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Store coordinates in TABLEE_COORDS
 */
public void addCoord(String name, String lat, String lng){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(CAR_KEY_LAT, lat); // latitude
    values.put(CAR_KEY_LNG, lng); //Longitude

    // Inserting row
    db.insert(TABLE_CARCOORD, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing writable database connection
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 * */
public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
    values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    return user;
}


/**
 * Getting user login status
 * return true if rows are there in table
 * */
public int getRowCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    // return row count
    return rowCount;
    }
public Cursor getUsername(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = ("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN + " WHERE name = " + KEY_NAME);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return cursor;
}

public Cursor getLatLng(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = ("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CARCOORD + " WHERE name = " + CAR_KEY_NAME);
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return cursor;

}


/**
 * reset table TABLE_CARCOORD
 */
public void resetCarcoord(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CARCOORD, null, null);
    db.close();
}
/**
 * Re create database
 * Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void resetTables(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
    db.close();
}
```

}

*Code snippet from UserFunctions.class where I use the table "coord".*

```
    /**
 * Get lat and lng from TABLE_CARCOORDS
 */
public ArrayList<String> getCoords(Context context, String lat, String lng) {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    Cursor cursor = db.getLatLng();
    ArrayList<String> cordarr = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        lat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
        lng = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lng"));
        cordarr.add(lat);
        cordarr.add(lng);
    }
cursor.close();
db.close();
return cordarr;
}
```

**LogCats after fix**

*First problem*

```
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.example.androidbasic12/databases/android_api' 
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:2072)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1126)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1083)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1170)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:844)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:228)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:231)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at com.example.androidbasic12.library.DatabaseHandler.getUsername(DatabaseHandler.java:146)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at com.example.androidbasic12.library.UserFunctions.getUname(UserFunctions.java:87)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at com.example.androidbasic12.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:59)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/SQLiteDatabase(20980):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 14:15:07.080: E/System(20980): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
01-22 14:15:07.085: E/System(20980): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Don't have database lock!
01-22 14:15:07.085: E/System(20980):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyLockOwner(SQLiteDatabase.java:2230)
01-22 14:15:07.085: E/System(20980):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2322)
01-22 14:15:07.085: E/System(20980):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2318)
01-22 14:15:07.085: E/System(20980):    at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:197)
01-22 14:15:07.085: E/System(20980):    at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:285)
01-22 14:15:07.085: E/System(20980):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.deallocCachedSqlStatements(SQLiteDatabase.java:2283)
01-22 14:15:07.085: E/System(20980):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeClosable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
01-22 14:15:07.085: E/System(20980):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:2043)
01-22 14:15:07.085: E/System(20980):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:185)
01-22 14:15:07.085: E/System(20980):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
01-22 14:15:07.085: E/System(20980):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

*Second error*

```
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidbasic12/com.example.androidbasic12.map}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at com.example.androidbasic12.map.onCreate(map.java:57)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
01-22 14:15:07.435: E/AndroidRuntime(20980):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: have you checked whether database has created or not.?

Comment: try to increment the DB Version: private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

and Uninstall the application and then reinstall.

Comment: Did u checked whether there is coordinate table in "File explorer" option.

Comment: Updating `DATABASE_VERSION=2` and reinstalling the application fixed this error. However I got several other errors. But my question on this topic is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you added below statement  `db.execSQL(CREATE_CARCOORD_TABLE);` in starting only(i mean both table together), or you added it later after creating database.

I will suggest you to **remove/uninstall the application from phone/emulator completely. and install it again** and see what it says on execSQL method call. I think if above was the case with you it should probably work.

> > The Reason here is onCreate calls once when database is not created hence if it is called once when  created db, later on if you add another table, onCreate wont be called hence no added table ll be created. so solution here is either remove app completely and install it again so onCreate ll call now. or increase our database version and do some handling.

Comment: ok,i know its there at oncreate, have u read my post completely?

Comment: yes i read that's i comment and tell you that first line should not be that (like have you added) one as he already has written that line...

Comment: oh ok, Will u please uninstall and reinstall the app and let us know the logcat, it will be great @silentKiller. I am here for a while can help u to solve it.

Comment: As I create both tables in the `onCreate` method, shouldn't they both be created? Or do you mean that the program only runs the first line `db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE)` ? However reinstalling and updating database version to "2" fixed this problem.

Comment: Hold on, I will paste my current logCat.

Comment: yeah that what i told , if u could uninstalled  it completly and installed again, it could have worked too. let me tell u the reason with example. Suppose u have created a table A(by writing db.execSQL(A)} and u sees it is working fine, then u tries to create table B doing the same, But it wont create table be, because onCreate wont call now, as database is already created with table A. so if u want to create table B ,u either need to reinstall app by removing preinstall app, or give dabase version a higher number. Have i made my self clear?

Comment: Ok thanks, now I understand! Could you have a look at my current logCats or should i do a new question for these?

Comment: Yes please have a new question, u ll get more responses in that. Please also write oncreate of ur activity where u using this ArrayList from db? as error pointing to activity.